# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected issue while calling a javascript method

Tags: javascript

i am calling a javascript method  and facing this issue. Please help me
Here is my code

```
protected void btn_PostBack_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string PageName = "", URL = "";
        int uploadID = 0;
        Session["DueData"] = hfSalesTax.Value;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ShowAlert", "Javascript:ClosePopUp()", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a semocolon after calling a javascript method

like :
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ShowAlert", "Javascript:ClosePopUp();", true);